# How to travel a graph and return a minimum path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a graph like this image :

[image]

now I create a dict and save path in it:

```
path_dict={
    '0':['5'],
    '1':['4','5'],
    '2':['1','3','4'],
    '3':['1','4'],
    '4':['1'],
    '5':['0','2','3','4'],
}
```

I hope can input the starting and end point,and return the minimum path like this:

```
>>>travel(1,5) 
>>>{'path':[1,5],'length':1}
>>>travel(0,2) 
>>>{'path':[0,5,2],'length':2}
>>>travel(4,0) 
>>>{'path':[4,1,5,0],'length':3}
```

Is there any easy method doing that? thanks a lot!

Comment: Dijkstra, perhaps?

Comment: yes,it solved my problem. Thanks!